# Android Studio 0.2.7 build exception with Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I'm in the process of migrating over to Android Studio from Eclipse.  Although since Android Studio is still in "Preview" mode, I am migrating slowly and incrementally.  Since updating to the newest version of Android Studio (0.2.7), I've come across an error in the default build process that prevents me from building ANY Android projects, even if I create a new "empty" project from within the new version of Android Studio.  When I click the "Run" button in Android Studio, I am presented with this error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':GradlePreview:packageDebug'.
class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

If I then run gradle from the command line in order to receive a more detailed stacktrace, I get this:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':GradlePreview:packageDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTaskWithCacheLock(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:47)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager.<init>(Packager.java:253)
at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.packageApk(AndroidBuilder.java:1039)
at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$packageApk.call(Unknown Source)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.groovy:72)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:248)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:136)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:248)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:136)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:213)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:202)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 53 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I've seen similar stacktraces posted on this site and I've implemented what was suggested but none of those solutions solved the problem for me.  This includes deleting/moving legacy versions of BouncyCastle out of my Java Extensions folder and I've also removed those files from the android-sdk/tools/lib directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating to jdk 6.0_45. 
I was having the same issues with jdk 6.0_26 but it's building ok after the update.

  Also make sure that you :
- have JAVA_HOME defined and it points to the new jdk
- Path variable contains JAVA_HOME
- update your sdk settings in Android Studio (close project, go to Configure/Project Defaults/Project Structure select JDK and point to the new jdk)

Comment: Thanks @Muerte!  I did end up downloading a new jdk from developer.apple.com, and I also had to change the the settings in Android Studio to point to the said new jdk.  And finally, I got it to work!

Comment: If you need to use JDK 1.7, I have found that only the x86 version works.

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to run the application may be because you didn't configure jdk/jre properly. Try making system variable PATH point to your ...\Java\jdk[version]\bin and CLASSPATH to ...\Java\jdk[version]\lib. Also, in android studio go to file>other settings> default project structure > sdks and navigate to your jdk install folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this totally applies, since you're running Ubuntu, but the same error on OSX was solved for me by changing the JRE that Android Studio was running under (following guidance from here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

I set the JRE version that Android Studio runs under to 1.7.* by changing this in the Info.plist file on OSX:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7*</string>
```

The version was confirmed in the "About" dialog. It changed from 1.6 to 1.7, and the BouncyCastle problem went away.

(Note: This was also my answer to a similar question here: [Gradle error in app:packageDebug, Android Studio, Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596483/gradle-error-in-apppackagedebug-android-studio-ubuntu/22311626#22311626))