# Gradle error in app:packageDebug, Android Studio, Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a project in Android Studio on Ubuntu but it fails with the following error in gradle.

`Error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.`
`> org/bouncycastle/util/Store`

I have been using Android Studio in Windows but never came across this error.

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579372/problems-launching-error-in-android-studio-when-packagedebug-at-max-os-x) but it didn't work.

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: This is also https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64737 but that bug report doesn't shed any more light on the problem.

Comment: Has this started recently? If so, what did you change to make it start happening? Can you please add your build.gradle file to the question?

Comment: My gradle.build is similar to what is posted in the bug report. But I will upload after I boot to linux. I didn't change anything in the app . It was my first time to run the app in linux. So I can safely say I downloaded the latest canary build and directly ran a dummy project.

Comment: Note that I have the same canary build in Windows and everything is running perfectly there. Hence the problem seems to be linux specific.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this totally applies, since you're running Ubuntu, but the same error on OSX was solved for me by changing the JRE that Android Studio was running under (following guidance from here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

I set the JRE version that Android Studio runs under to 1.7.* by changing this in the Info.plist file on OSX:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7*</string>
```

The version was confirmed in the "About" dialog. It changed from 1.6 to 1.7, and the BouncyCastle problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem in osx.

I clear the gradle files in ~/.gradle. Then reopen android studio, wait for download the gradle files, then everything is ok.