# Error when launching kickflip example app using Android Studio for Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.4. Recently i have started using android studio. I installed Homebrew and got installed gradle. I need to try the example for kickflip android SDK, so i checked out the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example). But the project is not getting launched. It is showing the error

`Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z`

I know similar questions has been asked in the stackoverflow itself.

[Problems launching error in Android Studio...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579372/problems-launching-error-in-android-studio-when-packagedebug-at-max-os-x)

[Android Studio 0.2.7 build exception with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705395/android-studio-0-2-7-build-exception-with-gradle)

[Gradle error in app:packageDebug...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596483/gradle-error-in-apppackagedebug-android-studio-ubuntu/22311626#22311626)

[Android Studio Bouncy castle issue (newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392675/android-studio-bouncy-castle-issue-newbie)

I tried the solutions provided in those but of no help.

I am using java 1.7.0_09. java -version gives

> java version "1.7.0_09"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

and the gradle is up todate. Please help if anyone encountered the same issue and got fixed.

Comment: My guess is you have two bouncycastle jars somewhere in your classpath

Comment: Hi @Saneesh.. i checked the dependencies and the jdk. There was one inside the jdk, and i removed that. Still its having the same issue.

Comment: Any luck in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Kickflip running under Eclipse Kepler. 
Here are the steps:
1. Download the android-sdk zip file from GutHub sdk
2. Import the sdk in Eclips
3. Move the files in java directory to src directory
4. Create a lib directory and move the armeabi directory in the lib directory
5. Move the lib jar files in the lib directory
6. remove the ffmpgwrapper jar file, because it also exists in the source directory, otherwise you get multiple dexes
7. increase the heap buffers in eclips.ini
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

Now it should work

Comment: The question was about getting it to run under Android Studio.